# regex (convert br and dash to li, or find dash between br tag)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can convert the "-" to list (li) on PHP? Example HTML:

```html
any text - any text  any text any text  any text any text 

<br><br>- any text any text<br>- any text 1 2 3 | \ ,<br><br>
<br>any text
```

I tried using the following regex:

`(<\s*[^>]*>-\s?(.*?)<\s*[^>]*>)`

But then only the first match can be found...

By this can find everything what I need - that start from the `<br>` tag, but it cannot set the end of the search (it will be in the `<br>` tag):

`<br>\s?-\s?(.*?)` (link to test: https://regex101.com/r/CqjpzX/1 ).

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you some sample input and output expected?

Comment: With your second approach, you write _but it cannot set the end of the search_. Why do you need to _set the end of the search_, when you just want to replace near the start of the match?

Comment: Decide what you want - _convert br and dash to li_, or only _convert the "-" to list (li)_, and write only one of these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're asking for, but if you want to capture everything between the `<br>-` and `<br>` you need to use a regex like this.
`<br>\s?-\s?(.*?)(?=<br>)`

Here is an example on your text https://regex101.com/r/71cHQB/1

I hope this can help you.

Also don't forget the /g after the regex so it doesn't stop after the first match.

Comment: OP wants to transform `-` into list, how do you get list from your regex?

Comment: If OP uses a code like this with the regex he transforms all `<br>-` into `<li>`.
```<?php

$input_lines="any text - any text  any text any text  any text any text 
<br><br>- any text any text<br>- any text 1 2 3 | \ ,<br><br>
<br>any text";

echo preg_replace("/<br>\s?-\s?(.*?)(?=<br>)/", "<li>$1", $input_lines);

?>
```
example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53bb719cb40c9854080f42ee8d597f56dd8244c5